# Why might everything but the gpsd status be unpacked?

Tags: c++, json, gps, embedded-linux, gpsd

Using libgps.so.25.0.0 built from gpsd-3.19.tar.gz for aarch64-linux-gnu embedded Linux target,
why might everything but the status (DGPS_FIX) be unpacked to (gps_data_t) m_gps_data during the gps_read?

```
int gps_bytes = gps_read( &m_gps_data, gpsd_msg, MAX_MSG_SIZE );
```

The status, mode, flags, etc. are visible in the libgps debug output

```
STATUS: status: 2 (DGPS_FIX)
MODE: mode: 3 (MODE_3D)
libgps: final flags: (0x5377c)
{TIME|TIMERR|LATLON|ALTITUDE|SPEED|CLIMB|STATUS|MODE|HERR|VERR|SPEEDERR|CLIMBERR}
libgps: gps_read() -> 270
```

and in the message (gpsd_msg) which is printed by my client

```
{"class":"TPV","device":"/dev/ttyACM0","status":2,"mode":3,"time":"2020-04-27T13:56:5
9.000Z","ept":0.005,"lat":26.343147000,"lon":-80.631992833,"alt":16.300,"epx":2.302,"
epy":2.153,"epv":7.878,"speed":0.004,"climb":0.000,"eps":4.60,"epc":15.76,"eph":3.990
,"sep":7.648}
```

but the m_gps_data.status (struct gps_data_t) seems to be the only thing that has not been unpacked.

```
PRINTF_2("gps_bytes %d status %d mode %d lat %g lon %g alt %g\n",
   gps_bytes, m_gps_data.status, m_gps_data.fix.mode, m_gps_data.fix.latitude,
   m_gps_data.fix.longitude, m_gps_data.fix.altitude);
```

(PRINTF_2 adds FILE, LINE, and func to printf)

```
nav_thread.cpp:277 (_thread_proc) - gps_bytes 270 status 0 mode 3 lat 26.3431 lon -80.632 alt 16.3
```

Building like this:

```
scons minimal=yes shared=True gpsd=False gpsdclients=False socket_export=yes clientdebug=yes 
    target='aarch64-linux-gnu'
```

Update: I am able to work around the issue by parsing the status from the message and using that to set the gps_data_t status field like this

```
           if (STATUS_SET == (m_gps_data.set & STATUS_SET))
           {
              if (NULL != strstr(gpsd_msg, "\"status\":1"))
              {
                 PRINTF_("STATUS_FIX\n");
                 m_gps_data.status = STATUS_FIX;
              }
              else if (NULL != strstr(gpsd_msg, "\"status\":2"))
              {
                 PRINTF_("STATUS_DGPS_FIX\n");
                 m_gps_data.status = STATUS_DGPS_FIX;
              }
```

but this does not fix the root cause

Comment: I've never used this library, but "everything but one struct element being unpacked" sounded fishy. Searched and found [this](https://gpsd-users.berlios.narkive.com/cu8wekdj/libgps-status-member-always-zero), which says libgps status isn't updated in every type of query. Hopefully that's the right direction to go in!

Comment: @thisisbenmanley - the problem is not that the status is not being updated, it is, as can be seen in the message which contains the sentence returned by the gps_read. It is just not being copied by the unpacker from the message to the struct gps_data_t

Comment: Why not to drop a mail to `libgps` authors and corresponding mailing list or bug tracker?

Comment: @0andriy done - thank you for the suggestion